# How i could save an array[] to an array[][] with two dimensional

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, netbeans

I had create an Array[] and i would like to save it in firsti column! So i had wrote this code:

```
String[][] SundaySounds = {{"0","0"}};  
String[] SundayArray = {"0"};

........

for (int i=0;i<SundayArray.length;i++)
    {   
        SundaySounds[0][i] = SundayArray[i];   <--line 39
        System.out.println(SundayArray[0][i]);
    }
```

And i get this error output:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at Test.main(Test.java:39)

Comment: Array indices start from `0`.

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays` in Java start at position `0`, not position `1`.

```
String[][] SundaySounds = {{"0","0"}};  
        String[] SundayArray = {"0"};


        for (int i=0;i<SundayArray.length;i++)
            {   
                SundaySounds[0][i] = SundayArray[i];//changed the index
                System.out.println(SundayArray[i]);
            }
```

Comment: So i correct and now it just print the first two element and the error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at Test.main(Test.java:39)

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt work, because in the second iterations you do the following:

```
SundaySounds[0][i] = SundayArray[i];
```

Here is i equal to 1. This is not possible becausw SundayArray doenst go further than 0

Answer (score 0):

The following code works just fine.....

```
String[][] SundaySounds = {{"0","0"}};  

    String[] SundayArray = {"0"};


    for (int i=0;i<SundayArray.length;i++)
    {   
           SundaySounds[0][i] = SundayArray[i];
    }    
        System.out.println(SundaySounds[0][0]);
        System.out.println(SundaySounds[0][1]);
```

> Output comes as 0 0

Try working it again.